# Tranparent background for UICollectionviewCells and for UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an ios app, and i currently struggle with a view im making. I want a view with two different collectionviews, where the first first collectionview is embedded in a viewcontroller (white background) then i have four cells inside it(yellow background).

My question is then, how do i make the cells (yellow) transparent or remove the color, so the gradient background is shown?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijg3n.jpg

I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow, but none of them seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, you can do this directly in the Interface Builder like so:

Select your collectionView and go to the properties inspector, on the right column you'll see backgroundColor, just set that to clear instead of the default white color, and that's it.

[image: InterfaceBuilder1]

[image]

Comment: I am making the whole ui and everything in code, so do you know how i do it programmatically ?

Comment: same thing, yourCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

Comment: Thank you, It worked with the viewcontroller! But the UICollectionviewCell wont respond to it, is there something else i should do for that?

Comment: do you have the code for the collectionView initialization? Do you do it with lazyvar or something like that?

Comment: it works now! I forgot to turn off cell.backgroundColor in the cellForItem function. 
But thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: great, glad I helped